# How are tags picked up for extensions in VSCode marketplace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I was going through some popular VSCode extensions in the marketplace but couldn't figure out how tags are picked up.

For example in the [VSCode python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), the tags are shown below:

[image: Python extension on VSCode marketplace]

I thought it's being picked from "keywords" in the [package.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/package.json#L48-L53) but there are just four keywords here. So how are the other tags picked?

Comment: It seems to be computed by Marketplace web portal, based on whatever private rules.

Comment: private rules as in, can you pls elaborate a bit?

Comment: https://github.com/vscode-restructuredtext/vscode-restructuredtext An extension with no keywords, and the tags come from the middle of nowhere. Isn't that a proof?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, I was just digging into the link you just shared can find most of them in languages under contributes https://github.com/vscode-restructuredtext/vscode-restructuredtext/blob/master/package.json#L108-L139

aliases  has restructuredtext, ReST, RST, and keybindings, snippets are in contributes. Could be wrong else it's as you suggested computed by marketplace based on private rules.